# Min and Max with duplication - SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have this table

```
courseId| courseNmae|Credits
------------------------------
100     |DB         |2
------------------------------
101     |CS         |3
------------------------------
102     |OS         |2
------------------------------
104     |AI         |4
```

And I want to retrieve the course names that having the min and max credits, I get confused because there are more than min values. So, How I can show the course Names that having min credits besides max values ? Thanks in Advance 
This is my Query

```
select min(credits),max(credits)
form courses group by courseName;
```

Comment: Well, you need `DB, OS, AI` courses ? are they as expected result ?

Comment: I need to get the names of courses with highest and lowest credits

Comment: You have 2 course with  lowest credit, do you need both of them ?

Comment: yes  i need both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select courseNmae from t 
where credit in (
    select min(credit) from t 
    union 
    select max(credit) from t 
)
```